# Spring Boot 2 подключение source файлов к html странице

Tags: java, html, css, spring-boot, spring-mvc

У меня есть контролер например вот этот:

```
@GetMapping("/shop")
    public String shopMain(Model model) {
        Iterable<Product> products = productRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("products", products);
        return "shop";
    }
```

Он возвращает страницу и все стили подключаются корректно:

```
===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
```

Но когда я использую в пути url еще один аргумент или боле через /, например был /shop или /greet (стили подключаются корректно), если я использую /shop/details. то стили перестают подключаться.
Насколько я понимаю нужно указать правильно путь, но каким образом и откуда он берет свои истоки, относительно чего его указывать я совершенно не понимаю. Подскажите пожалуйста!!!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для сителй абсолютные пути, например: `href="/css/util.css"`

Comment: в том то и дело, что для css например у него относительный путь от localhost указывается верно, а если там будет папка например с images то в путь относительно localhost будет не localhost/images а localhost/shop/images